# How call a view of xml to java code?

Tags: java, android, view

how  call how  call this view from my java code 
for show the white line

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/linea"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

this is onCreate

```
View line;
line = (View) findViewById(R.id.linea);
```

when select the button

```
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) 
                 {

 if(tipoo == 0){
                         double gr[] = con.Peso(y);
                     text1.setText(gr[0] + " kg\n\n"+ line+  gr[1]+ " gramos\n\n" + line+  +gr[2] +
                             " onzas\n\n"+gr[3]+" libras\n\n" + line+   +gr[4]+" Toneladas");
                     }
}
```

to separate with  lines the  text from on java code 
example

Hola
----------- (this is the view of xml code)
hi

" text\n"+ (line) +"text"+

I have bad english sorry :(

Comment: it's better, you can use listView then automatically shows your data in every single row...

Comment: or if you still want to do this using View then you have created at-least 4 View object in your xml file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
First import `import android.view.View;`
then write this line in your `onCreate ()` method

```
 View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.linea);
```

But it is not important to make an object ( of this View) for visibility . without any object a `View` would visible in your layout.

Comment: But I need call 3 line more of the java code when the client select a button

Comment: then first you need a Button object and set the setOnClickListner() method  .. post your java code please

Comment: that is the java code I need a line over every \n on the text

Answer (score 0):

Add `View` into your activity after `setcontentview(R.layout.layout)`

```
 View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.linea);
```